# Pandas map a dict of lists?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dict of lists, and I want to map/replace values in a column to the key of each item if one of the list values match, how can I do this?

For example:

```
   MappingDict = {
      'argenx SE': ['argenx SE',
      'Argenx SE',
      'ARGENX SE',
      'ARGENX SE NV',
      'ARGENX SE COMMON STOCK',
      'ARGENX SE ARGX',
      'argenx SE ADR'],

     'Arête Industries, Inc': [],

     'Ares Management Corporation': ['Ares Management Corporation',
      'Ares Management Corporation 7 % Non-Cum Pfd Registered Shs Series A'],

     'Alexandria Real Estate Equities, Inc': ['Alexandria Real Estate Equities, Inc',
      'Alexandria Real Estate Equities Inc 3.45 04/30/2025',
      'Alexandria Real Estate Equities Inc-3.45%-4-30-2025']
    }
```

I have dataframe that looks like this

```
df['Name']:
Name     
Alexandria Real Estate Equities Inc 3.45 04/30/2025
ARGENX SE NV
Arête Industries, Inc
```

I want it to result to:

```
df['Name']:
Name     
Alexandria Real Estate Equities, Inc
argenx SE
Arête Industries, Inc
```

Basically if the item in the list of a value matches then it should replace the column's value with the key. If the value of a key is blank then the value should just remain as it is. I've tried to replace and map to do this but it seems they are not designed to work with a dict of lists.  What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us try `explode` then `replace`

```
s = pd.Series(MappingDict).explode()
df['name_new'] = df.Name.replace(dict(zip(s,s.index)))
df
                                                Name                              name_new
0  Alexandria Real Estate Equities Inc 3.45 04/30...  Alexandria Real Estate Equities, Inc
1                                       ARGENX SE NV                             argenx SE
2                              Arête Industries, Inc                 Arête Industries, Inc
```

Comment: My DF is large so it's been running for 5 min. I'll let it run and let you know the result. I didn't know about the explode. If it works I may look if there a faster implementation or if it works with dask, etc.. Thank you Beny!